# How can I make an object float/stay in the air and not falling down?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Like idle, The object have now idle animation in the animator controller but the object fall down when running the game.

I want the object to idle but stay in the air and not falling down.

This screenshot show the object components and settings I tried to play with them but so far nothing helped.

The object just falling down when running the game. and I want the object to float/stay in the air.

[object components and settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBIor.jpg)

Maybe I need some script to attach to it and in FixedUpdate some how to add force to the object ?
I just want to keep the object hang in the air and then when using other scripts to move it that it will move to a target but first how to keep it in the air ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need other script. Just uncheck "Use Gravity" property in Rigidbody.

You can learn more from the official tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTGcs10Sj34

[image]